# Azure blob client-side encryption using Javascript

Tags: javascript, azure-blob-storage

I am working on Azure blob storage and using an HTML page with JS which is using Azure storage Rest API. I am able to Upload/Download blobs to my storage account. My requirement is to use client-side encryption for upload/download blobs so that files are encrypted before they are uploaded to blob storage account. There are few tutorials which explain this functionality using the library for .net/java and python, however, I am not able to find any documentation/sample to achieve this using JavaScript. Please help with any pointer which can help in my implementations.